# select result from three tables using sql

Tags: sql, select, multiple-tables

I want to get a result from three tables. i dont how to write the sql query. Please help me.

```
"I want to display Name,Username and Product_Name where Id=007"

table "register"

Name  Username  Id
Arj   arjun     007
xyz   abcd      008
abcd  asdf      007

table "products"

Product_Id   Product_Name   Price
101           Clothes        200
102           Games          100

table "purchase"     //products.Product_Id=purchase.Item

Username   item    Id
arjun      102     007
abcd       101     008
asdf       102     007
```

Comment: If you are learning SQL, you should really show what you have tried.  This is a fairly basic statement.

Comment: Look up INNER JOIN and WHERE.  If you still have trouble, post back here.

Comment: With those duplicate IDs and the duplication of names across the tables, I'm not even sure what you'd consider a correct result. Could you add the desired result to the question?

Comment: You should also always state your DBMS (Oracle, Postgres, ...) as some answers might depend on the specific SQL dialect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT a.Name,a.Username,c.Product_Name
FROM  register as a
JOIN purchase as b on a.Username=b.Username
JOIN products as c on b.item=c.Product_Id
```

It should work like this. To read more on SQL Joins try : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Username, Id, Product_Name 
FROM register 
INNER JOIN purchase ON purchase.Id = register.Id 
INNER JOIN products ON purchase.Item = products.Product_Id
WHERE Id = '007'
```

As a side note: you shouldn't save the Username in the purchase table too.

Answer (score 0):

That should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM
register r
JOIN purchase p on p.username = r.username
JOIN products pr on pr.product_id = p.item
```

you can revise this basic code to include specific columns and add where and order clause.